# Height is not being set on an InfusionSoft form

Tags: javascript, wordpress, iframe, infusionsoft

We've got an InfusionSoft form on a page (on a WordPress site) that is coming from the InfusionSoft javascript.

`<script type="text/javascript" src="https://uu145.infusionsoft.com/app/form/iframe/9ad1af7469e553f569dde3d29b09d319"></script>`

on this page:

http://www.heartofbusiness.com/foundations-one-clients-money-mini-series/

Some of our users are reporting that the form only partially shows (it's all there in the iframe, but the viewable area is about half the height of the form). Mostly in Chrome & Firefox on macs. Safari doesn't seem to ever have the problem, but it's not consistent as I'm able to see the form properly in both Chrome and Firefox on my mac.

Any thoughts as to why the height wouldn't be set properly?

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** I did some more digging on your webform and it looks like the issue presents itself in Internet Explorer. To fix the issue you can set a manual height on two elements.

- First set the div infFormDiv_0 to height of 360.
- Second set the height of the iframe to 360 as well.

CSS:

```
#infFormDiv_0 {
  height: 360px;
}
#infFormIframe_0 {
  height: 360px;
}
```

**Original Answer:**

It is hard to determine the issue if I can't see it myself. The form works fine in the multiple browsers I checked.

I would suggest you change from the javascript form to the HTML form anyways. This would most likely prevent the form from cutting off in the cuture.

Go to the forms details page and click Get the code and select the HTML unstyled version to get the HTML code you will need. Then style the form using CSS to get the look you want.